# Php find word in text using regular expression

Tags: php

I want to find the whole words in text not a sub string.
I have written following code.

```
$str = 'its so old now.';
$a   = 'so';
if (stripos($str,$a) !== false) {
 echo 'true';
} else {
 echo 'false';
}

str1 = 'its so old now.';
str2 = 'it has some issue.';
```

I want to find word 'so' in text. it give true in both the string. But I want true in first case only because in second string 'so' contains in 'some' words.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\b` can be used in regex to match word boundaries.

```
\bso\b
```

Should only match `so` when it is on it's own:

```
if(preg_match('/\bso\b/',$str)){
    echo "Matches!";
}
```

Note that `preg_match` returns `0` on no match and `false` on error so you may wish to check for these values. The above is also case insensitive. You can use `/\bso\b/i` to ignore case.

Comment: It's no working when I need to detect 'true' word in the haystack string. That means when the haystack is equal to 'true' or 'some text' it returns true in both!

Comment: @Babaktrad I think you have a mistake in your code. It does work for true: https://3v4l.org/DDmKV