# How to search for certain words in array in a sentence using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to search for certain word in a sentence. To that effect, I leverage solutions found ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)), which works fine for searching just a word.

My issue is that I need to search the words in the array in a sentence something like

```
$findme = array("food", "water", "salt");
```

How can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
$mystring = 'my best food is Jellof Rice';


$findme   = 'food';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'.";
}
else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring',";
    echo " and exists at position $pos.";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looping through an array of words to search for?

Comment: Must all words in the array be in the sentence or is it only about 1 match?

Comment: is going to be one match in the array at a time Remy for instance is If word salt in array is in a sentence print true, and so on

Comment: use ```in_array``` to find into an Array in PHP

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Comment: If a sentence has the word `salted` in it, should it match `salt`?

Comment: yes at John Conde. It should match salt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try something like this one

```
$mystring = 'text goes here';
$Found = false;
$findme = array("food", "water", "salt");
foreach($findme  as $singleValue ){
 if ($strpos($mystring, $singleValue ) != false) {
   $Found = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of also incurring hefty downvotes one possible method, if I understood correctly, would be to use a `regExp` and create a pattern using all the possible words from the `$findme` array.

```
$str='my fictional favourite food is Jellof Rice with salted water but not too much sugar and some rice';
#$str='banana apple mango';

$words=array( 'food', 'water', 'salt' );


function findmatches( $str=false, $search=array()){
    if( !empty( $str ) && !empty( $search ) ){
        # modify source array by quoting words if they require
        array_walk( $search, function( &$item ){ 
            $item=preg_quote( $item, '@' );
        });
        
        # generate the simple pattern by imploding all the words
        $pttn=sprintf('@(\w%s)@',implode( '|', $search ) );
        
        # try to capture all matches
        preg_match_all( $pttn, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
        
        # return a suitable result - the frst set of matches or false if not found
        return !empty( array_filter( $matches ) ) ? $matches[0] : false;
    }
    return false;
}

function showresults( $arr ){
    # utility to display the results
    if( !empty( $arr ) ){
        foreach( $arr as $i => $v ){
            printf('The word "%s" was found at position %s',$v[0],$v[1]);
        }
    }
}


$res=findmatches( $str, $words );
echo $res ? showresults($res) : 'Not found';
```

Which will output

```
The word "salt" was found at position 48
Array
(
    [0] => salt
    [1] => 48
)
The word "water" was found at position 55
Array
(
    [0] => water
    [1] => 55
)
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/5iMk2)

Comment: With all respect professor but this is so complicated for such trivial task.

Answer (score -2):

just use a loop, you can do that in a function

```
function findIn($string, $array) {
    foreach($array as $item) {
        if(strpos($string, $item) === false) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend to use a regex (PREG) expression.

1. If you have a single string, test for matches in that string.
2. If you have an array of strings with multiple occurrences, loop through each string in the array and apply the regex-expression.
3. If you need each word-occurrence just once, store results as keys in an associtaive array.

Same problem is discussed here: [Php find word in text using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786407/php-find-word-in-text-using-regular-expression)